# Time locked cryptography using Bitcoin difficulty param and/or smart contract?

Tags: cryptocurrency, timed-release

**Outcome**:  Create a message with a count down timer.  Once a top level password is entered, a countdown timer starts.  Once timer expires, the message is decrypted.

**Known methods**:  Proof of work.  User has to use computing power to decrypt the message.

**Problem**:  The computer power will change in the future.  I want relatively accurate time lock, now & years from now.

Are these possible solutions…?

Proof of work time lock tied to Bitcoin difficulty:  Bitcoin has a reactive difficulty parameter that will reflect current state of processing technology.

Is there anyway to use the Bitcoin difficulty parameter as to make a time locking message with a relatively accurate time lock time, now & in the future?

**Smart contract based**:  A smart contract, that once a first layer password is input, a count down timer starts, based on a time now oracle of some kind.  Once expired, the second layer message is decrypted.

**A)** Are any of these possible?

**B)** Are there any other existing solutions that would get the desired outcome currently?

**Removing serial hashing burden, but still getting the same benefit: **
When top level password is entered, BTC current block is noted.  When BTC block reaches current block + X, 2nd layer message is decrypted.

Possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are indeed the main known solutions. Note that your solution A has been explored in the cryptographic community, [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/482.pdf) is an example of a theoretical work on the subject, but I think there are others, more practical proposals for using the blockchain as a timer (it was discussed at length in a slightly different context in [this recent paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/253.pdf)).

Note 1: as far as I know, no such method has yet been evaluated and experimented in practice, yet alone deployed.

Note 2: a small correction to your first item, "proof of work": actually, a proof of work does not suffice here. This is because if the work involved is *parallelizable*, meaning the work can be divided across many CPUs, then there is no guarantee about the time it takes to complete the task - did the opponent use 1 CPU and time T, or T CPUs and time 1?

The right solution is to use proofs of *sequential* work, which demonstrate that the prover has executed T steps of a problem which is *conjectured to be impossible to parallelize*. Many examples exist, based mainly on the conjectured hardness to parallelize modular squaring (given a random $r$ and a modulus $n$, compute $r^{2^T} \bmod n$, where $n$ is an hard-to-factor RSA modulus). Many recent papers have worked on related constructions, e.g. look up "proof of sequential work" or "verifiable delay function".

A byproduct of using proofs of sequential work is that the work cannot be sped up with more CPUs, so the right user will just use a single CPU dedicated to solving it, which makes the work required somewhat less cumbersome (no need to have thousands of computers "farming" the proof).